# ¿Como obtener un numero aleatorio en un rango?

Tags: java, random

Me preguntaba come se podía obtener un numero aleatorio en java dentro de un rango. El numero tiene que ser un numero decimal que se encuentre en un rango determinado, pero aleatorio.

```
private Random random = new Random();

random.setSeed((long) (centralPoint.x*456 + centralPoint.y*456));

float num = random.nextFloat();
```

Pero con este programa me da un numero completamente aleatorio, sin rango.

Comment: acá hay un ejemplo

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Math/random

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Si lo que deseas es **obtener un valor aleatorio para un rango de números de punto decimal** se realiza de esta forma:

```
 Random r = new Random(); 
 resultado = r.nextFloat() * (maximo - minimo) + minimo;
```

Este es un ejemplo:

```
float maximo = 2.0f;
float minimo = 0.1f;
float resultado;
for (int i=0; i<100; i++){
     Random r = new Random(); 
     resultado = r.nextFloat() * (maximo - minimo) + minimo;
     System.out.println("Numero:" +resultado);
}
```

[Ejemplo online.](https://www.ideone.com/0X4Q1e)

---

Puedes **obtener un valor aleatorio de un rango de valores tipo entero** de esta forma:

```
   Random r = new Random(); 
   resultado = r.nextInt((maximo - minimo) + 1) + minimo;
```

Este es un ejemplo:

```
int maximo = 10;
int minimo = 3;  
int resultado;
for (int i=0; i<100; i++){
     Random r = new Random(); 
     resultado = r.nextInt((maximo - minimo) + 1) + minimo;
     System.out.println("Numero:" +resultado);
}
```

[Ejemplo online.](https://www.ideone.com/MbxlL6)

---

Comment: Lo siento pero esta respuesta no me sirve, para nextFloat, que es lo que quería, pero gracias, lo usare en otro momento.

Comment: @Pasblo por eso es importante ser especifico en las preguntas. Agregue la forma de realizarlo con valores Float.

Comment: Muchas gracias, no llevo mucho tiempo en esta plataforma y gracias a personas como tu puedo entenderla mejor. Gracias

Comment: @Pasblo si deseas ayuda aquí es el lugar correcto, entre todos nos ayudamos y obtenemos conocimiento, espero en un futuro tu me ayudes en mis preguntas!, muchos saludos!

Answer (score 1):

Prueba con esto, te permite obtener número decimales hasta con 2 lugares después del punto decimal. El 10 representa el máximo valor del rango y el 5 el mínimo, por lo que solo debes cambiarlo según tus necesidades. Ten en cuenta el valor máximo nunca sale como resultado.

```
(random.nextInt(10 - 5) + 5) + (float) (random.nextInt(100) / 100.0);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me ha servido también.